# React submit form returns event.preventDefault is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem with a simple form registration submit. Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';

import {register} from 'Util/api'

function Registration() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("")
  const [passwordCheck, setPasswordCheck] = React.useState("")
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("")

  const register = event => {
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.preventDefault()

    register(email, password, passwordCheck).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={register}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Email"
              value={email}
              onChange={ev => setEmail(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Repeat password:
            <input
              type="password"
              placeholder="Repeat password"
              value={passwordCheck}
              onChange={ev => setPasswordCheck(ev.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Register</button>
        {error && (
          <div>{error}</div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Registration
```

When I click the button "register" the console returns the error:

> Registration.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function

Same thing happen with `event.preventDefault` if I delete that line. It looks very similar to the example in the doc [here](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)...

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a name collision - there are 2 identifiers named `register`:

```
import {register} from 'Util/api'
```

and

```
const register = event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()

  register(email, password, passwordCheck).then(res => {
```

In the second code, you want to refer to the imported function, not the handler, but since the handler is lexically closer, `register` refers to the handler there - it calls itself recursively, with a first parameter of `email`, which is not actually an event, so `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` can't be called on it.

Use a different name:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  event.preventDefault()

  register(email, password, passwordCheck).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two register. Please change

```
const register = event =>
```

to

```
const submitHandler = event =>
```

and

```
<form onSubmit={register}>
```

to

```
<form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
```